# Using nested def for organizing code

Tags: python, coding-style

I keep nesting `def` statements as a way of grouping/organizing code, but after doing some reading I think I'm abusing it..

Is it kosher to do something like this?

```
def generate_random_info():
    def random_name():
        return numpy.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'])

    def random_value():
        return numpy.random.rand()

    return {'name':random_name(), 'value':random_value()}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it?  What do you gain by putting those functions inside the other, instead of making them global functions, or making them methods of a class?

Comment: I agree with BrenBarn, I cannot see how this format could be useful

Comment: It's only an organizational technique (nothing gained as far as performance). The definitions have no stand-alone meaning, therefore they would only be called through the parent `def`. Seemed cleaner to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it per se. But you should consider one thing when you use structures like this: `random_name` and `random_value` are functions that keep being redefined whenever you call `generate_random_info()`. Now that might not be a problem for those particular functions, especially when you won’t call it too often but you should consider that this is overhead that can be avoided.

So you should probably move those function definitions outside of the `generate_random_info` function. Or, since those inner functions don’t do much themselves, and you just call them directly, just inline them:

```
def generate_random_info():
    return {
        'name': numpy.random.choice(['foo', 'bar']),
        'value': numpy.random.rand()
    }
```

Comment: I agree that this example could easily be reduced to what you show, In practice the definitions might have significantly more code in them. Excellent note about the functions being redefined.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are planning on reusing the same chunk of code repeatedly throughout a single function and that function only, I would avoid creating those functions just for the sake of doing it. I'm not an expert on how the code is working on the computational level, but I would think that creating a function is more intensive than simply using that line as you have it now, especially if you're only going to use that function once.